# using active directory, NTLM and then accessing the users exchange unread emails

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, exchange-server, ntlm

I am building an intranet site and i want to display the users email(not the complete email), but the subject, from, date and time.

However, the first step would be connecting to the exchange server using the NTLM credentials, which are the same, however, i dont want the user to have to type their password to connect to the email.

is this possible and how?

any resources/examples anything to help me get started thanks

Comment: What kind of API are you planning to use to connect to exchange?  Most of the Windows API supports SPNEGO, which it means it would try to use Kerberos first.  If Kerberos is not supported, it would use NTLM.  Since you tag this question with "active-directory", I presume your Exchange server has joined to domain.  So, Kerberos authentication should always be used first, whenever possible.